# How to console.log each frame in the video as a byte array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, video-streaming

the following is the code that I use to stream from my webcam onto a video element.
I want each frame to be logged as an byte array in the console. Basically want to get each frame as a byte array. I'm a newbie so please provide a detailed explanation as to how I can approach this.

```
var video = document.querySelector("#video");

  // Basic settings for the video to get from Webcam
  const constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
      width: 475,
      height: 475,
    },
  };

  // This condition will ask permission to user for Webcam access
  if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function (stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
      })
      .catch(function (err0r) {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
      });
  }
  //console.log(context.drawImage(video, 0, 0));
  let a = document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.key === "Escape") {
      stop(e);
    }
  });

  function stop(e) {
    console.log("video stopped!");
    var stream = video.srcObject;
    var tracks = stream.getTracks();

    for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
      var track = tracks[i];
      track.stop();
    }
    video.srcObject = null;
  }
```

Thanks.